# HTML Table cell autosize

Tags: html, mediawiki

How do i set the cel width in a table so that it fits the entered text and not a fixed width but variable. the first cell has a fixed lenht of 30% followd by 4 cels that have text

Comment: Tables by default do that already, as long as you do not set the width for the rest of the cells. The remaining cells should automatically distribute widths according to content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by not giving the table a width in CSS and it will then resize based on the text within the table.

See the example below.

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Auto resize column to fit text</td>
<td>Example text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Example text</td>
<td>Example Text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```